# How can I pass a JPanel as a parameter to a method?

Tags: java, parameters, jframe, jpanel, parameter-passing

Let me ask.
I´m working in a java project in Netbeans. I've created a JFrameForm (Design mode), inside the JFrameForm, there is five (5) JPanel.

I've found a method por enable/disable all components inside a Jpanel. Works.

```
private void changeState(){
    for(Component c : mypanel.getComponents()){
        c.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
//mypanel it's one of a five panels in JFrameForm.
//I would like pass all the JPanel as parameters
```

I'm try writing a method where I can pass like parameter, just, the JPanel that I need when I invoced the method. Can you help me?

I'm try this,but don't work:

```
private void changeState(JPanel p){
    for(Component c : p.getComponents()){
        c.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

I'm sorry if the answer it's very easy. I'm beginner in JAVA and in this community. I hope you can help me.

Comment: what is the error of your method?

Comment: How are you calling it?  What are the results you getting?

Comment: It seems that I was wrongly invoking the parameter that passed to the changeState() method. It's my first week with JAVA. It's a great community, thank you very much!

Code works!

Answer (score 1):

But it does work! When I run the following code (with your method included) it gives me 2 x true, and then 2 x false. So the method is fine.

```
public class Panelik extends JFrame {
    JPanel panel;
    JLabel label1, label2;

    public Panelik() {
        panel = new JPanel();
        label1 = new JLabel();
        label2 = new JLabel();
        panel.add(label1);
        panel.add(label2);

        System.out.println(label1.isEnabled());
        System.out.println(label2.isEnabled());

        changeState(panel);

        System.out.println(label1.isEnabled());
        System.out.println(label2.isEnabled());
    }

    public void changeState(JPanel p) {
        for(Component c : p.getComponents()) {
            c.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Panelik panelik = new Panelik();
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that I was wrongly invoking the parameter that passed to the changeState() method. It's my first week with JAVA. It's a great community, thank you very much!

Code works! I test your code, works fine! Thanks!